# Core Data store empty after app update - but data model hasn't changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, automatic-ref-counting, magicalrecord

I am developing an update for an app that uses Core Data to persist data.
I use Magical Record to make dealing with Core Data easier.

This update doesn't involve any changes to the data model.

Yet, when I install the new update on a device, the existing data is deleted, and the app opens with an empty data store. There are no warnings or error message about data migration issues logged. The app also doesn't crash and shouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch is set to NO before the Core Data stack is set up (`[MagicalRecord setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:NO];`).

There are no subsequent Core Data issues (new data is persisted fine).

The main changes made to the app in this update are:

- Converted the app to ARC
- Converted the app to use CocoaPods for external libraries
- Updated the MagicalRecord library from v1.8.3 to v2.1

In my App Delegate I set up the Core Data stack using:

```
[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
```

Does anyone have any idea what can be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through the code starting at setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack.

Comment: Yes, but right after setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack executes, the store is already empty.

Comment: Did you change the app name (kCFBundleNameKey key in info.plist) ?

Answer (score 2):

When you have an empty store, generally it means your migration model isn't step up properly, or your model schema identifiers don't match the version identifiers for the data store.

Make sure you keep both versions of your core data model (before and after). This is how core data matches up the store with your model, and also how to know which version is the newest version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The thing is though, that the update doesn't involve any changes to the data model. There is no new version and I haven't been able to find any inadvertent change in the current version of the data model relative to the previous version of the app (which would explain the situation). Magical Record is also not throwing any errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: Just double-checked the diffs for the .xcdatamodeld file/directory, and there haven't been any changes to it since the last (successful) version migration.

Comment: I'd have to see what's going on with your app to really put my finger on it. If you don't have a new model version, a migration should not be triggered. Your store identiiers should then match the model and load. Can you check the identifiers of your store and model and see what entities are different?

Comment: This seems to be caused by a change in MagicalRecord as to where it stores the .sqlite file. It used to be (version 1.8.3) in the /Library directory. Now (version 2.1) it's in /Library/Application Support/{Application Bundle Name} and Magical Record searches for existing sqlite stores in /Library/Application Support/{Application Bundle Name} and /Documents - but not in /Library

Answer (score 2):

After deletion of the store, you need to specify that you want to replace the store with a new one automatically, as so.

`[MagicalRecord shouldAutoCreateDefaultPersistentStoreCoordinator];
[MagicalRecord setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:YES];
[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];`